# Why aren't my commits showing up in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, commit

I am a new programmer and trying to use Xcode's source control manager to keep track of changes to my code.

Right now I would like to revert back to a previously committed version of my project. However, in opening the Organizer, selecting Repositories, and selecting my project from the left project list, I can only see snapshots of my project.

The previously committed versions appear correctly when using the Version editor outside of Organizer.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this within Xcode but it is simple enough outside of Xcode.  The easiest approach would be enter the following in Terminal:

```
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit>
```

This won't revert on the current branch but will give you a new branch to develop off of.  If you really want to revert then simply:

```
git revert <commit>
```

with conflict resolution will work.

If you can't find 'git' within the Terminal then 1) install the Xcode command line tools or 2) look in the Xcode package under Xcode/.../usr/bin to find it.

Comment: Hi GoZoner: Thanks for letting me know that you can't revert in Xcode, that seems rather frustrating. As for the second half of my question...I was looking at the wrong project in the "Organizer - Repositories" window :S